# Magento 2.2.5: How Search In Category Product Work?

Tags: search, magento-2.2.5, banner-slider

I'm doing "Banner Sliders" module in magento 2.2.5, so I'm using module-catalog as example to do that.

You can see that in Admin page->Catalog->Category->Products In Category and you will see something like this:
[image]

So what I'm doing is almost exactly like that.

Here is what I've done til now.

[image]

But my search and filter doesn't work at all.

Whenever I click on "Search" and "Reset Filter" button, it throws this error:
[image]

So I want to know how this search work, so I can fix this. Because I'm kinda new to magento.

Here is my code:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Tab\Slide.php (This file is after module-catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product.php)

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * Slide in banner grid
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
namespace Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;

class Slide extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @var \Aht\BannerSlider\Model\SlideFactory
     */
    protected $_slideFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Aht\BannerSlider\Model\SlideFactory $slideFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_slideFactory = $slideFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('banner_slider_banner_slide');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    /**
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function getBanner()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('banner');
    }

    /**
     * @param Column $column
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
//        // Set custom filter for in category flag
//        if ($column->getId() == 'in_banner') {
//            $slideIds = $this->_getSelectedSlide();
//            if (empty($slideIds)) {
//                $slideIds = 0;
//            }
//            if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
//                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('main_table.id', ['in' => $slideIds]);
//            } elseif (!empty($slideIds)) {
//                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('main_table.id', ['nin' => $slideIds]);
//            }
//        } else {
//            parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
//        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_slideFactory->create()->getCollection();
//            ->addFieldToSelect(array('id', 'name', 'image'));

        if ($this->getBanner()->getId()) {
            $this->setDefaultFilter(['in_banner' => 1]);

//            main_table được lấy tự động.
            $collection->getSelect()
                ->joinInner(['banner_slide' => 'banner_slide'], 'main_table.id = banner_slide.slide_id', ['banner_slide_id' => 'banner_slide.id'])
                ->where('banner_id = ?', $this->getBanner()->getId());
//            hiển thị câu lệnh sql:
//            echo $collection->getSelect();die();
        }


        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Extended
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'in_banner',
            [
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'in_banner',
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedSlide(),
                'index' => 'id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'index' => 'id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn('name', ['header' => __('Name'), 'index' => 'name']);
        $this->addColumn('url', ['header' => __('URL'), 'index' => 'url']);
        $this->addColumn('image', ['header' => __('Image'), 'index' => 'image']);
        $this->addColumn('created_at', ['header' => __('Created Time'), 'index' => 'created_at']);
        $this->addColumn('updated_at', ['header' => __('Last Update'), 'index' => 'updated_at']);

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
//    public function getGridUrl()
//    {
//        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', ['_current' => true]);
//    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getSelectedSlide()
    {
        $slide = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selected_slide');
        return $slide;
    }
}
```

I've 3 tables.
 1. Banner
  [image]
 2. Slide
[image]
 3. Banner_Slide
[image]

Comment: what is error log in console ??

Comment: I was told by some one that i need to drop the comment in getGridUrl() function, so i'm following it, rightnow, it doesn't throw an error but still cant filter like what i want at all.

Comment: You must call parent in function **_addColumnFilterToCollection**

Comment: i dont understand what they do in that function .. can you please explain?

Comment: That function of the parent class, when you filter in the admin, Magento will call it for add a filter to your collection. When you add the comment for that function these fillers won't apply.

Comment: hmm, i'm checking it, thanks for your answers :)

Comment: may i ask 1 more thing?
in the _getSelectedSlide() function in the bottom of my block (Slide.php), what is the post('selected_slide') ? How can i post it and check it?

Comment: If you are using product grid you can find template **assign_products.phtml** to more info.